# Why doesn't my macro give any output

Tags: macros, clojure

I wrote a simple macro for printing out expressions and their results when debugging.

```
(defmacro dbg-print 
  "Print out values or expressions in context"
  [& rest]
  `(let [symb-str# (map str '~rest)
         symb-evl# (list ~@rest)
         pairs# (map #(str %1 %2 %3 %4) symb-str# (repeat ":") symb-evl# (repeat " "))
         str# (reduce str pairs#)]
     (printf "%s\n" str#)))
```

It works like this:

```
(defn my-func1
  [arg]
  (dbg-print (+ arg 1)))
(my-func1 1)
```

Which gives the output

```
(+ arg 1):2
```

Then I ran into a problem where I read something out of index:

```
(defn my-func2
  [first & rest]
  (dbg-print rest)
  (nth rest 1))
(my-func2 1 2)
```

This doesn't give any output at all. How can an error below the dbg-print macro, stop it from printing? I also noticed that the error goes away if I use println and format instead of printf in the macro. But I would still like to know whats going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a macro problem, but an I/O issue. You are encountering an exception before stdio is flushed.

`printf` uses `print` which uses `pr` without flushing.

`println` uses `prn` which uses `pr` but flushes when `*flush-on-newline*` is `true`.